# GWT Java MaterialRichEditor addPasteHandler

Tags: java, gwt

is there any way to watch the paste handler and sanitize the HTML before paste occurs..

Some event :

```
        getView().getRichEditor().addPasteHandler(new PasteEvent.PasteEventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onPasteEvent(PasteEvent event) {
                //howto cancel the event ? to sanitize pasted String
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to cancel the event just do: `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`.